# My Blender sculpt brush subtract mode color is set to blue but shows white instead. Why is that?

Tags: sculpting

In the Tool Shelf>Options Tab>Appearance>Show Brush(checked)>Subtract, I have set the color to blue because it is what I am used to in ZBrush. For some reason though, when I hold down Shift to smooth I get a white circle instead of the blue color that I set. Am I seeing a bug or doing something wrong?

Comment: I get the same. Looks like bug...

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for verifying that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really old question but the answer is that there are actually three colors for the brushes. One for add, one for subtract, and white for smooth. If you choose the 'Smooth' brush you'll see it is white. Holding 'Shift' with another brush is basically changing whatever you're using to a 'Smooth' brush.